# What will be the state of polarization?

Tags: optics, refraction, interference, polarization

[image]
When unpolarized light incident on the first polarizer, the light becomes plane-polarized with intensity equal to half of the initial value and the plane of polarization is parallel to the optic axis of the first polarizer. But I'm having trouble understanding what would happen when plane-polarized light passes through the Quarter wave plate. Following are my doubts:

1. When a plane-polarized light incident at the quarter wave plate at angle 45 degrees, then it will become circularly polarized and if it incident at an angle other than 45, then it will become elliptically polarized. However, the question does not tell me anything about the orientation of the Quater wave plate with respect to the first polarizer. So, what will be the state of polarization?
2. It is certain that the light coming from the Quarter wave plate will be either circularly polarized or Elliptically polarized. When this light passes through the second polarizer it will convert into a linearly polarized light. So, what will be the angle between linearly polarized light and the optic axis of the second polarizer?

Comment: My understanding is that they assume that the quarter wave plate is inserted as to create circularly polarized light. As you pointed out, the angle will define whether the output is linear(angle=0 or 90°), elliptical (angle $\neq$0, 90, 45, 135°), or circular (angle= 45, 135°). So, i guess they meant circular, which is the most common basic association to quarter wave plates.

Comment: But what will be the angle between the linearly polarized light and the optic axis of the second polarizer?

Comment: its on the question: 2 polarizers are ideal and perpendicular. Then you add other components in between. Obviously, after the second polarizer the angle of the light wrt the second polarizer is 0°...that's what a polarizer does.